# "Couldn't get GCM token for device" when trying to get the Push Token from my Android device in React Native but I get this error:

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to get the Push Token from my Android device in React Native, but I get this error :

> Couldn't get GCM token for device

```
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
    let finalStatus = status

    if(status !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
      finalStatus = status
    }

    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('No notification permissions!');
      return;
    }  
    let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()    
    console.log(token)
}
```

I've read that you need to add Firebase but I've also seen online examples without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mandatory to create a firebase-application for a standalone application.

Follow the FCM Guide:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-fcm/

Using the expo-app you can fix this error with the following steps:

1. Run your app using `expo start`.
2. Clear your apps cache
3. Log in to expo on your cli using `expo login`

Comment: logging in fixed the issue! Thanks!